# How to delete files listed in a text file

Tags: command-line, files

I have a text file that has a list of paths to various files. Is there a command I can use that will iterate through each line and delete the file at the stated path?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use [`xargs`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xargs.1):

```
xargs rm < file  # or
xargs -a file rm
```

But that will not work if the file names/paths contain characters that should be escaped.

If your filenames don't have newlines, you can do:

```
tr '\n' '\0' < file | xargs -0 rm # or
xargs -a file -I{} rm {}
```

Alternatively, you can create the following script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo -e "Usage: $(basename $0) FILE\n"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -e "$1" ]; then
    echo -e "$1: File doesn't exist.\n"
    exit 1
fi

while read -r line; do
    [ -n "$line" ] && rm -- "$line"
done < "$1"
```

Save it as `/usr/local/bin/delete-from`, grant it execution permission:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/delete-from
```

Then run it with:

```
delete-from /path/to/file/with/list/of/files
```

Comment: Really clean answer, but `cat` is not required, you can use `stdin` redirection: `< file xargs rm`

Comment: Its splitting names of folders up and then looking for them. E.g. MY FOLDER is being interpreted as "MY" and "FOLDER"?

Comment: @sudoman Answer updated.

Comment: If the files don't have spaces then you could just "rm -- $(cat file)" in bash or "rm -- `cat file`" in (ba)sh or csh.

Comment: @shooper `cat` is unuseful, as just stated, take advantage from `stdin`! Look at his updated answer

Comment: In the comment I made, the "cat" is useful kos, as it reads the file onto the command line, so that if you have a list of files in a file the $(cat file) expands to the contents of file and rm picks those up as arguments.  Try it (probably without rm).

Comment: @shooper In the comment you made `cat` is required in order to make it work, but the point is there's no reason to invoke a subshell for doing that!

Comment: @shooper I never said that it wouldn't work, i said that it would be overcomplicated

Comment: You can also handle "whitespace but not newlines" in the filenames with `xargs -d '\n' rm < file`

Answer (score 23):

Here's one way that can deal with file names with whitespace, backslashes and other strange characters:

```
while read -r file; do rm -- "$file"; done < list.txt
```

That will read each line of `list.txt`, save it as `$file` and run `rm` on it. The `-r` ensures that backslashes are read literally (so that `\t` matches a `\` and a `t` and not a TAB). The `--` ensures that it also deals with file names starting with `-`.

You could also do this in Perl:

```
perl -lne '$k{$_}++; END{unlink for keys(%k)}' list.txt
```

This one wil read each file name into the `%k` hash and then use `unlink` to delete each of them.

Answer (score 10):

Through python.

```
import sys
import os
fil = sys.argv[1]
with open(fil) as f:
    for line in f:
        os.remove(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Save the above script in a file named like `script.py` and then execute the script by firing the below command on terminal.

```
python3 script.py file
```

`file` is an input file where the path of the files you actually want to remove are stored.

Answer (score 4):

Silly, but here is one:

```
 tar -cvf /dev/null --remove-files -T filename
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this:

You can 'prepare' the file by making it a shell script:

```
$ sed -E "s/^(.*)$/rm '\1'/" input_file
rm 'file1'
rm 'file2'
rm 'file with some spaces.ext'
```

If your filenames may have a single quote (`'`), you can use this slightly expanded version to escape them first:

```
$ sed -E "s/'/'\\\''; s/^(.*)$/rm '\1'/" input_file
rm 'file1'
rm 'file2'
rm 'file with some spaces.ext'
rm 'a file with "quotes"'
rm 'a file with '\''quotes'\'''
```

And you can run this by piping it to `sh`:

```
$ sed -E "s/'/'\\\''; s/^(.*)$/rm '\1'/" input_file | sh
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you have a text file with the files with the complete paths. There are two possibilities:

1. Your list has the filenames separated by newlines, i.e. each line has the complete path to a file. in this case: here is a simple way out:

   ```
   for i in $(cat listOfFiles.txt); do
       rm -f $i
   done
   ```
2. If your list has one or more lines of filenames separated by spaces or tabs, then here is the drill:

   ```
   sed -i 's/\s\+/\n/g' listOfFiles.txt
   ```

   this will convert all whitespaces to newlines

   ```
   for i in $(cat listOfFiles.txt); do
       rm -f $i
   done
   ```

Yes, there are many ways to get it done, but this is a very simple approach.