# How to change script for deleting files while names misses symbols?

Tags: command-line, rm, xargs

I am trying remove files by names according this answer
[How to delete files listed in a text file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596489/how-to-delete-files-listed-in-a-text-file)

But get following error:

> rm: cannot remove 'var/Resources/Images/fd29d33d.jpg'$'\r': No such file or directory

I understand that every line in txt file misses an `/` at the start and something wrong with end of lines: `\r` in the end (except last file). How can I change this command `xargs rm < file` to work properly with my file? File contains about 8kk lines

It is not a homework, I am not an admin and need this to be done.

Comment: Did you create your text file on Windows? it looks like it has DOS-style (CRLF) line endings

Comment: @steeldriver no, it has been generated by program, microsoft .net btw

Comment: So ... not Windows but Microsoft ... regardless, either fix the program to use the appropriate EOL, or fix the file by removing the carriage return characters. See for example [How to change Windows line-ending to Unix version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/803162/how-to-change-windows-line-ending-to-unix-version)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, will try. How can I add `/` in front of every line also?

Comment: That's probably not necessary provided that all the paths are rooted at the same directory (e.g. `/`) - you'd just need to `cd` to that directory first so that they are all valid relative pathnames.

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a `/` at the beginning of each file, and to remove the trailing characters after the first `'`, you can try this command instead of `xargs rm < file`:

```
sed 's/^/\//' file | sed "s/'.*$//" | xargs ls
```

If the above command correctly lists the files, you must change `ls` to `rm` so that the files are actually deleted, this way:

```
sed 's/^/\//' file | sed "s/'.*$//" | xargs rm
```

I hope this helps.